# Unexpected rspec behavior Ruby on Rails Turorial chapter 12

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I am seeing an error that is only dependent on the location of the line:

```
should change(Relationship, :count).by(-1)
```

For example, with the code:

```
it "should destroy a relationship using Ajax" do
  lambda do
    xhr :delete, :destroy, :id => @relationship
    response.should be_success
  end.should change(Relationship, :count).by(-1) #<<-line is here
```

I get the rspec error:

```
  1) RelationshipsController DELETE 'destroy' should destroy a relationship using Ajax
     Failure/Error: xhr :delete, :destroy, :id => @relationship
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template relationships/destroy with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:js, :html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "#<RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering::PathSetDelegatorResolver:0x00000100a5b5f8>"
     # ./app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:16:in `destroy'
     # ./spec/controllers/relationships_controller_spec.rb:44:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/relationships_controller_spec.rb:43:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

But with the code:

```
it "should destroy a relationship using Ajax" do
  lambda do
    xhr :delete, :destroy, :id => @relationship
    response.should be_success
    should change(Relationship, :count).by(-1) #<<-Line moved to here
  end
```

... the test passes.

I am seeing expected behavior when I use a web browser.  Unfollowing a user adjusts totals correctly.

So, are these two rspec tests not equivalent?  Am I falsely reassured that the second test passes?  If they are functionally equivalent, why does the first one fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this was due, in part, to having confused

```
./app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb
```

with

```
./spec/controllers/relationships_controller_spec.rb
```

Code pasted into the wrong file (appropriately) generated no syntax errors. Fixing my error lead to passing rspec tests.